# ChartJS: Show percentage of a hidden data in tool-tip of a Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, percentage

I have a Pie Chart with Multiple rings like this:
[image: Pie Chart]

Below is the code generates the above chart with a hidden data `label: "Target"`:

```
 var data = [{
        labels: ["India", "US", "China", "Canada"],
        data: [55, 60, 75, 50],
        label: "Target",
        hidden: true
    }, {
        labels: ["India", "US", "China", "Canada"],
        data: [30, 32, 38, 45],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#4b77a9",
            "#5f255f",
            "#d21243",
            "#B27200"
        ],
        borderColor: "#fff",
        label: "Achieved"
             }, {
        labels: ["Arrivals", "Departure"],
        data: [8, 13],
        backgroundColor: [
            "#92d400",
            "#bbb"
        ],
        borderColor: "#fff"
    }];
```

I am showing the tooltips with below code:

```
 tooltips: {
   callbacks: {
   label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].labels[tooltipItem.index];
var values = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
var total = 0;
for (var i in values) {
    total += values[i];
}
var percentage = Math.round((value / total) * 100);
var totally = total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex !== data.datasets.length - 1) {
    return [label + " : " + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' (' + percentage + '%)', "Total : " + totally];
} else {
    return [label + " : " + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' (' + percentage + '%)', "Total : " + totally];
    }
}
        }
    }
```

With the above tooltip code, I am able to show percentage of Sum of total pie for each value.
However, I would like to achieve two things:

1) In the first ring, Show percentage of Target `label: "Target",hidden: true` vs Achieved `label: "Achieved"`. Percentage values in the Tooltip will be [India: 54.54%, US: 53.33%, China: 50.66%, Canada: 90%]

2) In the second ring, don't show any percentage and Total as well.

Here is the JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/9hj024wy/7/)